# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\rpt_payment_history.php on line 48

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to export mysql data to pdf using php I get below errors;

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\rpt_payment_history.php on line 48

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\rpt_payment_history.php on line 52

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\rpt_payment_history.php:48)' in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\fpdf.php(1052): FPDF->Error('Some data has a...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\fpdf.php(999): FPDF->_checkoutput() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\rpt_payment_history.php(57): FPDF->Output() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\SwaziTour\fpdf.php on line 271

My Code is as below;

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("select p.payment_id, u.company, p.description, p.payment_date, p.amount, p.status 
                                 FROM payment p
                                 left join user u on p.user_id = u.user_id
                                 order by p.payment_id desc")or die(mysql_error());

    $header = mysql_query("SELECT UCASE(`COLUMN_NAME`)
    FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
    WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='crud' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='payment'
    and `COLUMN_NAME` in ('payment' p,'user u')");
    require('fpdf.php');
    $pdf = new FPDF();
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
    foreach($header as $heading) {
        foreach($heading as $column_heading)
            $pdf->Cell(95,12,$column_heading,1);
    }
    foreach($result as $row) {
        $pdf->Ln();
        foreach($row as $column)
            $pdf->Cell(95,12,$column,1);
    }
    $pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: mysql results __must be__ fetched.

Comment: Welcome! You can't just iterate over the result of `mysql_query`. It's a resource which can be passed to other functions, like `mysql_fetch_array` to actually fetch the record. Some examples are given in [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). Also please note that this function is old and is replaced with other libraries like PDO. If you're learning now, better learn about PDO than about the mysql_* functions. See the big red box at the top of that documentation for more info.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13243080/php-warning-invalid-argument-supplied-for-foreach)

Answer (score 0):

you don't actually fetch the data after running the query. read up on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php , and maybe try something like

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT UCASE(`COLUMN_NAME`)
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='crud' 
AND `TABLE_NAME`='payment'
and `COLUMN_NAME` in ('payment' p,'user u')");

while(false!==($heading=mysql_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC))){
    foreach($heading as $column_heading)
        $pdf->Cell(95,12,$column_heading,1);
    }
}
```

- or even better, read http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers - the mysql_ api you're using was deprecated in PHP 5.5, and completely removed in PHP 7.0, you shouldn't use it at all today if you can avoid it.